# Performance bechmarking of MPI program in C

Tags: benchmarking, mpi

I am new to MPI.Can anyone please suggest me how to do benchmarking of MPI programs in C. Cluster I am using is running Rocks 4.3(Mars Hill).

Answer (score 0):

You could put an MPI_Barrier call at the beginning of the program, and then have each process record the time since the epoch and compare the final time-since-epoch with that at the end...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some parts of the answer, focussing on execution time:

- Familiarise yourself with the MPI_WTIME function.
- Have a poke around the [Top 500](http://www.top500.org/) and see what they do about benchmarking.  This might spark some ideas.
- Plan to compare execution time for: serial program, MPI program running on one processor, MPI program running on N processors (for a range of Ns).  Much benchmarking of parallel programs is about assessing their parallel scalability.

There's lots more, refine your question and you might get more apposite answers.